# Alternative to Firefox's Tab Groups feature for Chromium/Chrome

Tags: chromium, add-on

I've been using Chromium instead of Firefox, but I really do miss the Tab Groups Firefox feature, which is great to group tabs and organize them, it really is a boost on my productivity. Are you aware of any add-on which is similar for Chrome/Chromium? I've searched around on Chrome's Web Store but no luck at the moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<del>Give TabSugar a try.</del>

TabSugar seems to be defunct, its homepage redirects to spam.

---

Also on Chromium Store: [Group Your Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/group-your-tab/acdchnhopobbnjfibnecpnilpgkcjgnl)

Comment: Thanks, Tab Sugar is in fact very close to Tab Group view, I will try it right away!

Comment: FYI, lots of reviews on Tab Sugar spanning from 2010-2012 are suggesting that the current version is very buggy ("This has become too buggy to be usable", "Next to useless"...).

Comment: I'll add that as of this writing it is still rather unstable; selecting tabs from the interface of the addon opens new windows every single time.

Comment: The TabSugar link redirects to a spam website